# Python file not found error handeling

Tags: python

```
import csv
try:
    with open('test.xlsx',newline='') as csvfile:
        except errno.ENOENT
            print("opps !! no such file")
        dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))
        csvfile.seek(0)
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect)
        for row in reader:
            print(row)
```

the error I get

```
  File "<ipython-input-59-b3b9b540a1d8>", line 4
    except errno.ENOENT
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to place the `except` block at the same level as the `try` block, and add a colon, and use the right exception:

```
try:
    with open('test.xlsx',newline='') as csvfile:
        dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))
        csvfile.seek(0)
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect)
        for row in reader:
            print(row)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Oops! No such file")
```

If you only wanted to catch the `open()` call and not include the rest of the `with` block in the `try..except` handler, you need to open the file separately, *then* use it in the `with` block:

```
try:
    csvfile = open('test.xlsx',newline='')
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Oops! No such file")

else:
    with csvfile:
        dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))
        csvfile.seek(0)
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect)
        for row in reader:
            print(row)
```

Note that `errno.ENOENT` is not a valid exception to catch, it is only a constant. I used the [`FileNotFoundError` exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#FileNotFoundError) instead; it is a subclass of `OSError` that is thrown when the file you tried to open was not found.